# .htaccess: should I use general rule or a few specific rules?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am creating a webapp which consists of a very few main scripts.
And I wonder - is better AND faster to use some specific rules (from about 10 to 20)

Or is it better to use some general rule e.g. `http://example.com/go/my/boy`
would come to `go.php?my=boy` ?

This question is (more or less) about **PERFORMANCE** :)

**EDIT:** I dont have the resources to make a performance test by myself.

Comment: Then test the performance?

Comment: If you can make a rule that fits all your needs I'd do that. The more rules you have, the more grunt work you'll need to perform once something changes.

Comment: (1) if your URL-rewriting is a bottle neck on _any_ level, you are either doing some _very_ strange rewriting, or your application is blessed with exceptional performance (2) don't ever use a `.htaccess` file if you care about performance, those rules should by in your webserver or `vhost` configuration (3) truthfully, it probably doesn't make any noticeable  difference.

Comment: I assume we're referring to mod_rewrite and RESTful URIs... as a general rule of thumb, unless they are obscenely complicated with the potential to loop and redirect redirects or be abused with URI manipulation, fewer rules in your .htaccess is better. A general purpose rule also has the added advantage that you can sling it in a <VirtualHost> in httpd-vhosts.conf and forget about it.

Comment: So all you guys suggest that general rule is better ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are splitting hairs. As far as Apache performance when it comes to rewrites, alias & redirects there is a very slight performance hit when you add more rules. But it is negligible to imperceptible in practical use. And FWIW, this is a fairly common rookie perception when it comes to Apache performance.

Meaning, if you are worried about application performance, optimizing your application itself—and not the Apache web server—will give you the best & most measurable performance improvements.

Comment: To support your claim about performance hit. I've seen a developer (mistakenly) create a htaccess (via php but only once) to redirect almost a thousand url's. The website was being used intensively. After the save the server crashed because Apache memory couldn't handle that many rewrites for each visitor.

Comment: Between 20 and 0 I agree. However comparing thousands to tens is a major difference. In the case of TS it doesn't make a difference though.